# Handling multiple profiles for a single user with res.locals

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I'm creating a single user - multi profile website like Netflix, and after authenticating the user, I encode `user._id` (from the DB) with jwt and send it to the client, later for the secure routes, I decode the jwt token and find the user details and store them in `res.locals.user` ( in `requireAuth` and `optionalAuth`), I use this `res.locals.user` in various places, but I also want the profile that is under use to be stored in `res.locals` to use it in other routes (after the `requireAuth` or `optionalAuth` middleware).

I first login and do authentication and send the jwt token, but on the next screen I select the profile, and have everything exclusive to that profile, home page, me page, search other peoples page, etc, but I want the current profile that is under use, to do activities related to that user, so to do that I tried to store `currentProfile` in `res.locals`, but I cant do that in the login method itself.

My approach is that after the user clicks on a particular profile, a `getProfile` method/route is called (in the backend), and I modify the `authToken` to contain `user.id` and `profile.id`, `user.id` for checking authentication later on and `profile.id` for helping me to do other things.

I want to know if there is a better way to do things or are there any changes that I have to make this one better.